# Drop rows if any of multiple columns have duplicates rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop duplicates rows of either in columns `A` or `B` from the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 1, 2, 3, 4], "B": [2, 3, 7, 5, 5], "C": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]})
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  1  3  2
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3
4  4  5  4
```

My expected output will like this:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3
```

Obviously `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False)` will not generate what I want.

The following code works, but a little bit long. Just wonder if there are other more concise solutions? Thank you.

```
df.drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates('B', inplace=True)
print(df)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with chaining by `&` and inverting by `~` if only few testing columns:

```
df = df[~(df['A'].duplicated() | df['B'].duplicated())]
```

Or if want testing more columns use list of columns with `np.logical_or.reduce`:

```
df = df[~np.logical_or.reduce([df[x].duplicated() for x in ['A', 'B']])]
```

Or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = df[~df[['A', 'B']].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated()).any(1)]

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `duplicated`:

```
df[~df['A'].duplicated() & ~df['B'].duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3
```

Comment: Just tried with your code, it didn't generate the output as in question, do you get same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code

````
df.drop_duplicates('A' or 'B', inplace=True)
print(df)```
which give output as 

   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
2  2  7  3
3  3  5  3

Hope this will work for you..
````